# Arel AND clause and Empty condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

Consider the following code fragment:

```
def sql
  billing_requests
  .project(billing_requests[Arel.star])
  .where(
    filter_by_day
      .and(filter_by_merchant)
      .and(filter_by_operator_name)
  )
  .to_sql
end

def filter_by_day
  billing_requests[:created_at].gteq(@start_date).and(
    billing_requests[:created_at].lteq(@end_date)
  )
end

def filter_by_operator_name
  unless @operator_name.blank?
    return billing_requests[:operator_name].eq(@operator_name)
  end
end

def filter_by_merchant
  unless @merchant_id.blank?
    return billing_requests[:merchant_id].eq(@merchant_id)
  end
end

private

def billing_requests
  @table ||= Arel::Table.new(:billing_requests)
end
```

In method `filter_by_merchant` when merchant id becomes empty, what should be the value that must be returned for Arel to ignore the AND clause effect?
Also, is there a better way to handle this case?

Comment: So far as I can tell, there aren't any arguments that you can pass to `and` that make it do nothing.

Comment: have you tried "return billing_requests.all " ?

Answer (score 7):

You should return true. When you run .and(true) it will eventually get converted to 'AND 1' in the sql.

```
def filter_by_merchant
  return true if @merchant_id.blank?

  billing_requests[:merchant_id].eq(@merchant_id)
end
```

Comment: In my case I had to return `Arel.sql('TRUE')`, otherwise it would raise an `unsupported: TrueClass` error.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible to give any arguments to `and` that cause it to do nothing. However, you can just call `and` conditionally:

```
def sql
  billing_requests
  .project(billing_requests[Arel.star])
  .where(filter_by_day_and_merchant_and_operator_name)
  .to_sql
end

def filter_by_day
  billing_requests[:created_at].gteq(@start_date).and(
    billing_requests[:created_at].lteq(@end_date)
  )
end

def filter_by_merchant
  billing_requests[:merchant_id].eq(@merchant_id)
end

def filter_by_operator_name
  billing_requests[:operator_name].eq(@operator_name)
end

def filter_by_day_and_merchant
  if @merchant_id.blank?
    filter_by_day
  else
    filter_by_day.and(filter_by_merchant)
  end
end

def filter_by_day_and_merchant_and_operator_name
  if @operator_name.blank?
    filter_by_day_and_merchant
  else
    filter_by_day_and_merchant.and(filter_by_operator_name)
  end
end  

private

def billing_requests
  @table ||= Arel::Table.new(:billing_requests)
end
```

It's extremely clunky, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @wally_altman, I tried according to what you mentioned. But the following is what I get.  https://gist.github.com/midhunkrishna/985523a2041305eb817b

Comment: Hey you're right, it doesn't work! I've updated my solution.

Comment: @wally_altman, this doesn't answer the question. Besides, what if I also have to filter by another parameter, say 'operator_name'? I have updated the question.

Comment: Updated my answer. If you have even more parameters to filter by, you could extend this solution.

Comment: @wally_altman, that is not a maintainable solution. If I have pretty complicated query, I could "extend" it to make it pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sql
  billing_requests
  .project(billing_requests[Arel.star])
  .where(conditions)
  .to_sql
end

def conditions
  ret = filter_by_day
  ret = ret.and(filter_by_merchant) unless @merchant_id.blank?
  ret = ret.and(filter_by_operator_name) unless @operator_name.blank?
  ret
end

def filter_by_day
  billing_requests[:created_at].gteq(@start_date).and(
    billing_requests[:created_at].lteq(@end_date)
  )
end

def filter_by_operator_name
  billing_requests[:operator_name].eq(@operator_name)
end

def filter_by_merchant
   billing_requests[:merchant_id].eq(@merchant_id)
end

private

def billing_requests
  @table ||= Arel::Table.new(:billing_requests)
end
```